# differentiation of Laplace transform solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am wondering if there is a solution to the differential equation (of sorts):
$$\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}\left[y(t)\right]-\mathcal{L}\left[\frac{d}{dt}y(t)\right]=0$$
Using the fact that:
$$\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}\left[y(t)\right]=-\mathcal{L}\left[ty(t)\right]$$
we can show that the equation is the same as:
$$\mathcal{L}\left[ty(t)\right]+\mathcal{L}\left[y'(t)\right]=0$$
One case that would clearly work is:
$$y'+ty=0$$
Which would give:
$$y=e^{\frac{t^2}{2}+C_1}$$
Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No because the only solution to $\mathcal{L}(f) = 0$ is the function $f \equiv 0$.

Then you are able to use linearity of the laplacian operator to get

$\mathcal{L}(ty+y') = 0 \iff ty+y' = 0$.